# Ubuntu Server - Not being able to create files but directories in my home

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, filesystems, file-permissions

Im connecting through ssh to an ubuntu server (16.04) and for some reason im being unable to create files within my home directory, however im being able to create directories within it. No output is given at all when for example I use touch or an editor like vim to save my file

In my specific example, im trying to import a public key into this server for authentication,

i have no problems when creating the .ssh folder and modifying permissions

```
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh/
```

but when i cd into .ssh and run

```
touch authorized_keys
```

nothing happens (No output errors, no nothing)

Do you know why can this happen?

As additional information, this server has a proftpd server running

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers

UPDATE:

As suggested, here is my output

```
user@server:~/.ssh$ touch test
user@server:~/.ssh$ echo $?
0
user@server:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Mar  2 14:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 user user 4096 Mar  2 14:22 ..
```

Comment: The touch command isn't supposed to output anything, but the file should still be created. Is this happening?

Comment: @JosephSible the file is not created

Comment: Immediately after the `touch` command, run `echo $?` and then `ls -la` and post the output of both.

Comment: @JosephSible I have updated my question with the output for the commands you suggested, thanks in advance

Comment: What does `type touch` show?

Comment: Does `touch filename` work in other directories?

Comment: Can you create files in other ways, like `echo > authorized_keys`?